# disable AngularJS ng-click in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can disable a button with `ng-disabled` in AngularJS.

```
<button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
   Previous
</button>
```

But how can I do the same thing when I'm using `<a>` tag?

This is not working

```
<a ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
   Previous
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `<a>` tag doesn't have a disabled state. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

So you'll have to have a condition that checks if the `currentPage` variable should be changed.

You could use ternary operators, which are available since Angular 1.1.5.

```
<a ng-click="currentPage = currentPage ? currentPage - 1 : 0">
   Previous
</a>
```

The condition is basically saying that `currentPage` should be 0 if `currentPage` is 0, if it's not 0, then `currentPage - 1`.

Do note that Angular is not keen on having control flow statements in your HTML, see No Control Flow Statements here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression. You should instead create a function like so:

```
<a ng-click="prevPage();">
   Previous
</a>
```

And then define it in your controller:

```
$scope.prevPage = function(){
    if ($scope.currentPage > 0) $scope.currentPage = $scope.currentPage - 1;
};
```

Comment: Heh, was just typing this out, but you got to it first. Upvote.